# VB.NET calling a WCFservice in windowsphone 7.1

Tags: vb.net, wcf, windows-phone-7

I am trying to call the function getTemp(value as integer) from my webservice service1. When I execute the code it gives an error saying that `_value` is nothing.

If I call the same function in a normal windowsforms project it runs perfectly.

Does anyone have a solution ?

See my code below (import statements omitted):

```
Dim _value As String

Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim client As New Service1Client
    AddHandler client.GetTempCompleted, AddressOf getTempgotten

    client.GetTempAsync(3)

    MessageBox.Show(CStr(_value))

End Sub

Public Sub getTempgotten(sender As Object, e As GetTempCompletedEventArgs)
    _value = CStr(e.Result)
End Sub
```

PS: I'm new to this forum, so forgive my mistakes.